# Android RadioGroup arranged in a circle

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I'm trying to find a way to organize a single group of radio buttons into a circle shape. All I can think of is a complex setup of RelativeLayouts, but it gets messy when switching devices. Please help!

Comment: You might need to write your own custom viewgroup for this purpose.

Comment: [This blog](http://blog.mikeweng.com/2013/06/on-android-circular-style-layout.html) describes one approach to achieving a circular layout, based on a relative layout.